# Supremum of group combined with continuous function

Tags: limits, functions, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f(x)$ be continuous in $[a,b]$

Let $A$ be the set defined as:
$$A = \{ x \in [a,b] \mid f(x) = f(a) \}$$

1. Does $A$ have a maximum? I guess it it is the max value in $[a,b]$ which $f$ sends to $f(a)$ but I don't know how to prove it.
2. Would it still have a maximum if $[a,b]$ would turn into $[a,b)$?

Comment: Just so you know: the term is su-**pre**-mum, not su-**per**-mum.

Comment: A supremum is always defined. You're probably asking if there is a maximum.

Comment: Supremum, noted to myself. Harnak you are right, I meant maximum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is a subset of the bounded set $[a,b]$, $A$ is also bounded, and since $a\in A$, $A$ is not empty. Consequently, $A$ has a supremum, $s$, say. Note that this reasoning does neither require $f$ be continuous nor that $b$ is contained in the interval (as long as $a<b$, but if $a=b$, $[a,b)$ doesn't make any sense.).

However, if you are interested in showing that (or if) $s$ is also a maximum, you need to use the continuity: Since $A=f^{-1}(\{f(a)\})$ is the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function, $A$ is closed and hence contains $s$. Thus, $s$ is even the maximum.

Here is another way to show this: Since $s=\sup(A)$, there is a sequence $(x_k)\subset A$ converging to $s$. Thus, $f(x_k)=f(a)$ for all $k$, and since $f$ is continuous, $f(s)=f(a)$, showing that $s\in A$, so $s$ is indeed the maximum of $A$.

Comment: And what happens when $[a,b]$ turns into $[a,b)$? Why is there no maximum in that scenario?

Comment: If $[a,b]$ is replaced by $[a,b)$ with $a<b$, then $s=b$ can happen. For example, consider $[a,b)=[0,1)$ and $f(x)=0$. Then $\{x\in[0,1)\ |\ f(0)=f(x)\}=[0,1)$, and this set has no maximum (it would be 1).

Comment: "Since $A=f^{-1}(\{f(a)\})$  is the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function, $A$ is closed". If $f$ was not continuous, wouldn't A still be closed?

Comment: Not necessarily. For instance, let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$. Then $f^{-1}(\{f(1)\})=f^{-1}(\{1\})=(0,\infty)$, which is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ its a closed set because $A=f^{-1}(f(a))$ and $f$ continous, so $A$ has a supremum and $\sup(A)=\max(A)$, because morever $A$ is bounded in this case.
more precisely in a separate localy compact spaces, compact sets are whom bounded and closed, so $[a,b]$ is compacte, because the point $f(a)$ is closed and $f$ continous so $f^{-1}(f(a))$ is colsed and bounded by the continuity of $f$, so it's also compact.
and will steel in the secode case because $A$ steel closed.

Comment: The idea here is correct, so I've upvoted.. That cancels a previous downvote (since removed). But the spelling errors  and confusing grammar (not your fault since I suspect English is a second language) mean this is probably not useful for the OP. See @sranthrop 's answer. But thank you for trying.

Comment: yes that corret english is my third language, and i dont use is it ofen, beacasue my second language is french and isn't easy to master multiple language at the same time + my specialty.